# What is the support of this torsion sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the field of complex numbers. Let $ F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ such that $c_1(F)$ is algebraically and hence numerically trivial. Assume further that rank $F$ is zero.

Can we say something about Support $F$? Can it be a divisor or will the codimension be $\geq 2$?

What about in the case when the Picard number of $X$ is 1?

Comment: If $X = \Bbb P^3$ and $F = i_* \Omega_Y$ where $Y \subset X$ is a $K_3$ surface, then $F$ has rank zero and is supported on a divisor. Moreover, $c_1(F) = 0$ since the canonical bundle of a $K_3$ is trivial.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, isn't $c_1(F)=[Y]$? Why is that numerically trivial?

Comment: I made a very stupid mistake and did assume that if $c_1(\Omega_Y) = 0$ then $c_1(i_*\Omega_Y) = 0$ but it does not work of course, so you can ignore my comment and I can delete it if you want. Sorry about it.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, Don't worry about it!